# Openoffice Calc - use cell font color in formula

Tags: worksheet-function, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

I have some openoffice calc sheets where some rows are maked with
the font color red. All other rows are in the default font color.

Can I use the font color of a cell within a formula to react to this
or is this impossible?

Example:
Assuming I have column A with red and black cells, how would I create a column B that has "1" if A is red and "0" if A is black?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You might want to start [here](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_STYLE_function)

Comment: This points to the STYLE command that lets me set the color.
I'm looking for something that lets me read the color to use in formulas. I'm updating the question to make this clearer...

Comment: Use the style function to pull the color from the adjacent cell. Like an `if(T(style(` type function or similar

Comment: AFAIK this doesn't work. STYLE() returns 0 independet of the the current style. Additionally, the documentation states explcitely: *"There is no direct way to determine (in a formula) what formatting has been applied to a cell."*

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19313486/267197) explains how to do it via user-defined macro e.g. `=IF(CELL_BACKCOLOR(SHEET(); ROW(); 1) = 0; "I am black"; "I have another color")`.

Comment: The nearest thing I can come up with in native open office is this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-getcustomlistcontents-method-excel  - In other words, if your color formatting is conditional on the number being negative, you could get it to work.